# How to adjust size of accessory view in UIAlertView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview

I am trying to show image in alert view and am using the following code:

```
let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert", message: "Alert + Image", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
let imvImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 100))
imvImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
imvImage.image = objModelClass.creatorImage

//   alertView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 150, height: 150)
alertView.setValue(imvImage, forKey: "accessoryView")

alertView.show()
```

The problem is even though the image is correctly sized, not the alert view like [image: enter desciption image]

Comment: First of all `UIAlertView` is deprecated in iOS 9, use `UIAlertController` instead. You never do such things with alert, for achieving the above mentioned behaviour you should create a customised view and present it to user, rather than tweaking uialertview

Answer (score 1):

> *Side note: `UIAlertView` is deprecated. `UIAlertController` is the current way to manage alerts.*

---

So it’s interesting. There is no need to specify the image size in code. The image is represented as is, the true size of the image.

On testing, `UIAlertView` appears to calculate the size of the image display area based on device width and height in combination with `UIViewContentMode`. This means the results can be different on different sized devices. As `UIAlertView` has a width of 540 pixels, the best solution is to have an image of 540 pixels x 304 pixels (16:9 ratio) or less. This ensures the alert size is the same on iPhone as it is on iPad. Images with a width greater than 540 pixels present in unexpected ways.

Out of all the hacks floating around though attempting to add images to `UIAlertView`, this method actually respects the title and message area of the `UIAlertView` and allows `accessibilityLabel` and `accessibilityHint` to function. It also doesn't inhibit the `UIAlertView` buttons.

The below works on device and simulator for iOS 8, 9, 10 and 11 beta. (The `UIAlertView` also works in iOS 7 except for the image which is not displayed.)

Just make sure to point exactly to the correct image name otherwise a blank space appears.

---

**Code**

```
let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Alert title", message: "Alert message.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Image")
imageView.isAccessibilityElement = true
imageView.accessibilityLabel = "Image label"
imageView.accessibilityHint = "Image hint."
alertView.setValue(imageView, forKey: "accessoryView")
alertView.show()
```

---

**Image**

`UIAlertView` with 540 pixels x 304 pixels image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in accessoryView imageview size take according to image's real pixel so reduce resolution of your image which you are using

Comment: can you please explain in detail? if possible, with code